# vCenter VUM version for my application

Tags: virtualization, vmware-vsphere

I have ESXI 5.1 u1 loaded on the three 520's in our VRTX.  This is the latest version currently support by the Dell VRTX system.

I am managing with version 5.5 of the vCenter appliance.

My question revolves around the version of VUM that I should install.  If I install VUM 5.5 will it try to update the hosts to 5.5?  Should I install 5.1 version of VUM instead?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should install version 5.5  of the Update Manager software on a Windows system. It will not try to modify your hosts' revision level unless you explicitly tell it to.